# Searching for contacts with smartface

Tags: android, ios, contacts, smartface.io

I would like to show my users a list of their contacts with a phone number.  I tried to create a filtered list using the getAll method, but I found it too slow.

So I would like to allow the user to search for a name, and then I would return the contacts who name match the query.  Is this possible in smartface?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. 
You can use a repeatbox object in order to list contacts, and use a dataset for binding of that repeatbox. And when you write the appropriate sql statement(select) into that dataset, it will work for search.

Or you can search google for some search algorithms and use one of them. For example, you can use an editbox object, or a searchbar objects, and when its text is changed you can call your search function.

Comment: I have used a repeatbox to list the contacts with data from a dataset.  However, I need to iterate through each contact using the GetAll method.  This is the part that is slowing down the app.  Is there a way to do this without iterating through the GetAll results?